# Issue when deploying Symfony project to prod server

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony and I have encountered an issue where my routes return a 404 error. Everything is working fine on my dev environment but I don't know how to deploy my project on the prod server. I've probably missed a step somewhere.

So here is one of my controller named **HomeController** :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'home')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }


    #[Route('/pc', name: 'home_pc')]
    public function pc(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('home/pc.html.twig');
    }
```

When I do this following command `php bin/console debug:router --show-controllers`. The console  prints the following so I guess Symfony knows my different routes.

```
 --------- -------- -------- ------ ------ ----------------------------------------
  Name      Method   Scheme   Host   Path   Controller
 --------- -------- -------- ------ ------ ----------------------------------------
  home      ANY      ANY      ANY    /      App\Controller\HomeController::index()
  home_pc   ANY      ANY      ANY    /pc    App\Controller\HomeController::pc()
 --------- -------- -------- ------ ------ ----------------------------------------
```

And then, when I try to access `mywebsite.com/pc` for example, it just gives me a blank page and a [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3IpO.png).

Can anyone help me with my issue? Maybe you'd need another file to see what's wrong?

Comment: what do you get on url mywebsite.com/ ?  what kind of hosting do you have?  did you redirect(maybe it's the wrong word, but you need to tell your server to start reading websites from symfony public folder) public_htmo to (symfony/public) ?

Comment: The same thing, a blank page and a 404 error. I'm using cPanel but I don't have a symfony directory. Everything is in public_html

Comment: symfony starts from public (you have it in public_html)  directory   and that.s the issue

Comment: Ok I'm just dumb. I've deleted everything and recreated a new project and I can access the to my routes! And now I have a symfony directory. But the only issue now is that I have to go to the following address ```mywebsite.com/symfony/public/pc``` Now I'd like to delete *symfony/public* from the url

Comment: It is a hosting server issue.  You need to point your server directly to the public directory.  Exactly how you do that depends on the server and the host.

Comment: Indeed I finally found how to do that, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try put this .htaccess content in public_html  directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Even if  it works it  shouldn't be done this way, so  think of it as a temporary solution